# How to save images from local cache in WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, facebook-php-webdriver

I download images from a webpage via WebDriver (Chrome) by

```
// STEP 1
$driver->get($link);

// STEP 2
$els=$driver->findElements(WebDriver\WebDriverBy::tagName('img'));

foreach ($els as $el) {
$src=$el->getAttribute('src');
$image=file_get_contents($src);
file_put_contents("image.jpg",$image);
}
```

While the images have already been loaded by the browser, I need to download the images again in STEP 2.

I can save the images after STEP 1 by `right-click` in the browser and `Save image as ...` without an internet connection because the images are available in the local cache of the browser.

Is it possible to save the images loaded by *Chrome* with WebDriver without downloading them again?

The above code is `PHP`, but any hit or example codes in other programming languages can solve the problem.

Comment: you can use selenium with python or java (there is more languages supported) and take a screen-shot of an element.

Comment: @moeassal screenshot is not a rational way to save an image. The image is already on my local machine in the browser cache. I am sure there is a way to catch it.

Comment: Have you tried accessing cached data manually? from %appdata%\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below java code will download the image(or any file) in your desired directory.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class imageDownload{

       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
              URL img_url = new URL("image URL here");
              String fileName = img_url.getFile();
              String destName = "C:/DOWNLOAD/DIRECTORY" + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("/"));

              InputStream is = img_url.openStream();
              OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destName);

              byte[] b = new byte[2048];
              int length;

              while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                     os.write(b, 0, length);
              }

              is.close();
              os.close();
       }
}
```

First, all the bytes stream of your image will be stored in the object 'is', and this bytes stream will be redirected to OutputStream object os to create a file(kind of copy-paste, but as a 0's and 1's).

Comment: This is not a proper answer.